# Why does changing one entry in a 2D array change the entire column?

Tags: java, arrays

```
//main method
int one = 1;
int[] ones = {one, one, one};
int[][] lotsofones = {ones, ones, ones};
lotsofones[0][1] = 2;
for (int[] array : lotsofones) {
  for (int num : array) {
    System.out.print(num + " ");
  }  
  System.out.println();
}
/*
Expected output:
1 2 1 
1 1 1
1 1 1 

Actual output:
1 2 1
1 2 1 
1 2 1 
*/
```

Why is this happening? I don't understand. Why is it changing the entire column instead of just the single entry?

How do I achieve changing only one entry without initializing the 2D array differently? Is it possible?

Comment: Because of this: `int[][] lotsofones = {ones, ones, ones};`. Each index holds the exact same reference to `ones`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it changing the entire column instead of just the single entry?

Because each column, of each row, is the element stored in one same array object on the heap, and changing element in the array referenced with `ones`, will reflect that change in every other variable, which refers (or will refer) to the same array instance.

```java
int one = 1;
int[] ones = {one, one, one}; //creates 1D array `{1, 1, 1}`
int[][] lotsofones = {ones, ones, ones}; //reuses and puts the same "ones" array, object in three indices of "lotsofones" 2D array
```

Therefore, changing:

```java
lotsofones[0][1] = 2;
```

changes entry in ONE array object, that is referenced three times.

---

> How do I achieve changing only one entry without initializing the 2D array differently? Is it possible?

Sure, it is. Just create 2D array by not using the *same array object* for every element of that 2D array. One way would look like this:

```java
int one = 1;
int size = 3;
int[][] lotsofones = new int[size][size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < lotsofones[i].length; j++) {
        lotsofones[i][j] = one;
    }
}

lotsofones[0][1] = 2; //this will now change one particular element on one 2D array, instead of changing element in an array that is re-used over and over.
```

Then,

```java
for (int[] array : lotsofones) {
    for (int num : array) {
        System.out.print(num + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

will output:

```
1 2 1 
1 1 1 
1 1 1
```